# how to preview the Doc files in canvas

Tags: html, canvas

how to view the .pdf, .doc, .csv files preview using canvas is it possible to do that. I need to implement in my react project is any other way to do this?

Comment: https://dsctal.space/2018/03/27/how-to-embed-a-doc-in-canvas/ , does this link help?

Comment: Thanks, @tushar_lokare can u share me any example code

Comment: why do you need a code if you are using canvas